# SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find out a script that can help me in Data Density of my DBs. the point is I already figure out the query and what I do need but the problem is the query takes for ever. it works find for small DBs, but that doesn't happen a lot. 
So I am looking for kind of optimization or any ideas to help me.
the script:

```
DECLARE Cur CURSOR
FOR
SELECT DB_Name() AS DatabaseName
,s.[name] AS SchemaName
,t.[name] AS TableName
,c.[name] AS ColumnName
,'[' + DB_Name() + ']' + '.[' + s.NAME + '].' + '[' + T.NAME + ']' AS FullQualifiedTableName
,d.[name] AS DataType
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types d ON c.user_type_id = d.user_type_id
 WHERE d.NAME LIKE '%int%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%float%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%decimal%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%numeric%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%real%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%money%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%date%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%datetime%'

AND is_identity = 0

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT
FROM Cur
INTO @DatabaseName
,@SchemaName
,@TableName
,@ColumnName
,@FullyQualifiedTableName
,@DataType


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- The FETCH statement was successful.
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SET @SQL = ' Select ''' + @DatabaseName + ''' AS DatabaseName, ''' + 
@SchemaName + ''' AS TableName,
  ''' + @TableName + ''' AS SchemaName,
  ''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS ColumnName,
  ''' + @DataType + ''' AS ColumnName,

  (Select MAX(' + @ColumnName + ') from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName + ' with (nolock)) 
  AS MaxValue,
  (Select MIN(' + @ColumnName + ') from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName + ' with (nolock)) 
  AS MinValue,
  (Select COUNT(*) from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName + '   with (nolock)) 
  AS CountValue,
  (Select COUNT(*) from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName + ' Where ' + @ColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL ) 
  AS NotNULLCount,
  (Select 0 from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName + ') 
  AS DataDensity'

PRINT @SQL
```

The following script will give me the MAX, MIN, COUNT, NotNULLCount and the DATA DENSITY for every and each column form the declared types above. but u can imagine a DB with 70 tables and each table has 30-50 columns....
running this script will take for ever.

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(`right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics)` and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Pasting server version also helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try and avoid using cursors, this query will give you a list of select queries that you can copy and paste to get the data that you require. Note also I have removed the sub selects as they are not required:

```
SELECT 'Select ''' + DB_Name()  + ''' AS DatabaseName, ''' + s.Name + ''' AS SchemaName,  ''' + t.Name + ''' AS TableName,  ''' + c.Name + ''' AS ColumnName,  ''' + d.Name + ''' AS ColumnName,' +
 'MAX([' + c.Name + ']) AS MaxValue,' +
 'MIN([' + c.Name + '])  AS MinValue,' +
 'COUNT(*)  AS CountValue,' +
 'COUNT([' + c.Name + '])  AS NotNullCount,' +
  'CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT [' + c.name + ']) AS float) / COUNT([' + C.Name + '])  AS DataDensity ' +
  'from [' +  DB_Name() + '].[' + s.Name + '].[' + t.name + '] with (nolock)'
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types d ON c.user_type_id = d.user_type_id
 WHERE d.NAME LIKE '%int%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%float%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%decimal%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%numeric%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%real%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%money%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%date%'
OR d.NAME LIKE '%datetime%'
AND is_identity = 0
```

This will give you a list of select statements in the following form:

```
Select 'MyDB' AS DatabaseName, 'dbo' AS SchemaName,  'MyTable' AS TableName,  'ID' AS ColumnName,  'int' AS ColumnName,MAX([ID]) AS MaxValue,MIN([ID])  AS MinValue,COUNT(*)  AS CountValue,COUNT([ID])  AS NotNullCount,CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT [ID]) AS float) / COUNT([ID])  AS DataDensity from [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] with (nolock)
```

Of course SQL Server stores these sorts of statistics for useful columns, You can find which ones it has be using:

```
EXEC SP_HELPSTATS 'MyTable', 'ALL'
```

Then using the list of statistics returned such as:

```
_WA_Sys_00000014_004FB3FB   ID
```

to get the actual stats using:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('MyTable','_WA_Sys_00000002_004FB3FB')
```

This will return data like:

```
Name    Updated Rows    Rows Sampled    Steps   Density Average key length  String Index    Filter Expression   Unfiltered Rows
_WA_Sys_00000002_004FB3FB   Jan  8 2017  8:01PM 16535   16535   200 0.2493151   4.459389    NO  NULL    16535
```

and

```
All density Average Length  Columns
0.0006038647    4.459389    EffectiveDate
```

and another rowset showing a histogram of values.

You can automatically generate these `DBCC` commands using:

```
SELECT  'DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS([' + OBJECT_NAME(s.object_Id) + '],''' +  s.Name + ''')'
FROM sys.stats s 
  INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns sc
    ON s.object_id = sc.object_id AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id
  INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND sc.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE s.Name LIKE '_WA%'
ORDER BY s.stats_id, sc.column_id;
```

Comment: actually that is good solution but although I need a cursor to execute all the select statements in the table cuz at the end the result table is what i need